# Как с помощью PIL распознать изображение?

Tags: python, pil

Допустим, у меня есть картинка (к примеру, шарик) и я хочу узнать есть ли этот шарик на другой картинке, при этом шарик всегда будет один и тот же, он не будет ни искажаться, ни еще что-нибудь. То есть мне нужно, чтоб я спросил эта картинка здесь есть? и он ответит, допустим, `True` (ну или еще что-нибудь, неважно, главное знать, что он тут есть) с помощью PIL.

Comment: На обеих картинка может присутствовать только по одной фигуре? Цвет совпадает?

Comment: да фигура только одна. да, цвет тоже одинаковый

Comment: эти фигуры ПОЛНОСТЬЮ совпадают!

Comment: Вокруг шарика на картинке-образце какой-то фон или прозрачные пиксели? Т.е. насколько просто построить маску?

Comment: я могу и такой и такой шаблон сделать, смотря какой проще

Answer (score 3):

Если вас интересует *"техника"* решения этой задачи, и для вас вполне сгодится прямолинейный способ решения, то можно поступить примерно следующим образом.

> *(Из документации `PIL`)*
>
> **`ImageChops.difference(image1, image2) => image`**
>
> Returns the absolute value of the
>   difference between the two images.
>
> `out = abs(image1 - image2)`

***Тривиальный алгоритм*** - пройтись по всем возможным расположениям образца в изображении и, если верно, что `difference == 0` для всех пикселей, то вы нашли полное совпадение. Итерации по пикселям выполняются по строках в границах `{0, image.Width - sample.Width}, {0, image.Height - sample.Height}.`

- Можно также затвикать такой подход для того, чтобы он был инвариантен относительно `Exposure` и прочих параметров образца, подробнее смотрите [**на stackoveflow.com.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images)

---

Понятно, что с практической точки зрения этот **`O(W * H)`** алгоритм можно назвать *"наивным",* и такой подход сравним, например, с поиском подстроки в строке за **`O(N ^ 2)`.**

Если вас интересуют более `production-ready` решения, которые быстрее *(или же инвариантны относительно растяжения, скейлинга и других трансформаций)*, то стоит смотреть в сторону `OpenCV` и, соответственно, [**биндинга к python.**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html)

- В этой библиотеке представлены специфичные *матчеры,* покрывающие большой спектр задач, начать знакомство можете с функции [**cvMatchTemplate,**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/object_detection.html) которая производит поиск совпадений и выдает результат по некоторой заданной метрике.
- Для так называемого [**Feature Matching**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/feature_detection.html) на практике обычно используются алгоритмы `SIFT / SURF`, реализации которых также представлены в `OpenCV`.